# TV Movie: Villain absorbs glass to heal

Tags: story-identification, movie, cyborg

I recall watching a movie in the late 90's or early 00's that involved a nanotech-enhanced cyborg, who I believe was some sort of experiment or secret military project in an otherwise normal near-future setting. He seemed to be the villain, and was hunting the main characters (a hero and love interest, if I'm not mistaken). He was stronger, faster, etc, than a normal human, and could heal extremely quickly, but needed to absorb the silica in glass to replenish lost mass.

At one point, he has his arm cut off in what looked like an office promenade, and as he runs past a window, blue, snakelike tendrils come out of the stump to "eat" a swath out of the glass while his arm regrows. Later on, he falls from a high ledge into a bunch of glass, being impaled and cut up all over by the shattered glass. Overall, this only slowed him down as he was able to repair using the glass.

I got the impression this was a TV movie; the glass-absorption blue tendril effect was impressive CG, but I don't recall any famous actors or anything in it. It is also worth noting that the cyborg had no special effects or props when not injured; he just looked like a normal man.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This sounds like [Virtuosity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtuosity), in which SID 6.7 (Russell Crowe), a virtual gestalt of various criminals' minds, is able to enter the real world as a glass-based cyborg.

Here's a clip of SID 6.7, falling to be impaled on a bunch of glass, and then projecting blue, snake-like tendrils from his arm stump to absorb the glass.

Comment: Yep, that's it alright. I was clearly wrong about the film having no big names. ;)

Comment: @Vanguard3000 Haha, yeah, but your descriptions were otherwise pretty spot-on.

Comment: @Vanguard3000 - Remember the date of the movie. At the time, Denzel was a rising star, just getting notice (This was the time of Glory and Philadelphia), and 5 years before Gladiator for Crowe. Also Kaley Cuoco before she became big, etc. Other than DW, the rest really were minor or no name stars at that point.

Comment: @JohnP I like your comment because it makes me feel like I have a good memory. ;) You're right though. After looking at Wikipedia's "Critical Reception" section, I'm assuming this isn't the movie that kickstarted their careers.

Comment: @Vanguard3000 - No, not really. It could be argued that it was a step back for Denzel. He was just getting to be a "hot" commodity, Glory (Best supporting nomination) was 89, Malcom X (Another nomnination) in 1992, and this movie was not all that well received.